# Unrecognized options "scheme, cluster, url" under "lopi_pusher"

Tags: symfony, pusher

I'm using **LopiPusherBundle** for  Getting following error while clearing the cache in symfony 2.7.26

```
[Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException] 
Unrecognized options "scheme, cluster, url" under "lopi_pusher"


# app/config/config.yml
lopi_pusher:
    scheme: http
    host: api.pusherapp.com
    port: 80
    cluster: ap2
    timeout: 30
    debug: false
    app_id: <app_id>
    key: <key>
    secret: <secret>
    url: <scheme>://<key>:<secret>@<host>[:<port>]/apps/<app-id>
    auth_service_id: my_channel_authenticator
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your installed version is smaller than 1.3 and these options are not available.

You can see this here https://github.com/laupiFrpar/LopiPusherBundle/blob/1.2.9/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php

Check your composer.json and make sure the correct version is there

You can just use

```
"laupifrpar/pusher-bundle": "*"
```

Dont forget to update your dependency after modifying composer.json using

```
composer update "laupifrpar/pusher-bundle"
```